# Lipschitzian function implies uniformly continuity - choice of delta

Tags: uniform-continuity, lipschitz-functions

On this [link which is french page of uniformly continuity](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuit%C3%A9_uniforme#Fonctions_lipschitziennes), it is said that if a function is k-Lipschitzian, then this function is uniformly continuous.

They say that by choosing a $\delta$ as :

$$k\delta \leq \epsilon$$

Shouldn't it be rather $\delta$ as :

$$\delta \geq \epsilon/k\quad\quad?$$

Indeed, for a fixed $\epsilon$, we want to choose a $\delta$ as :

$$\dfrac{f(x+\delta)-f(x)}{\delta} = \dfrac{\epsilon}{\delta}$$

Moreover, we have with k-Lipschizian definition :

$$\dfrac{f(x+\delta)-f(x)}{\delta} \leq k$$

So we can choose $\delta$ as :

$$\dfrac{\epsilon}{\delta} \leq k$$

which is equivalent to: $\delta \geq \epsilon/k$, isn't it ?

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *want* $\left|\frac{f(x+\delta)-f(x)}{\delta} \right| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{\delta}$ or to be more precise:
$$\left|\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{\delta} \right| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{\delta}, \forall y \text{ such as } |x-y| \leq \delta$$
And you have:
$$\left|\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{\delta} \right| \leq  \frac{k |x-y|}{\delta}\leq k, \forall y \text{ such as } |x-y| \leq \delta$$.

So you have to choose $\delta$ such has:
$$a \leq k \Rightarrow a \leq \frac{\epsilon}{\delta}$$
or in term of intervals:
$$(0,k] \subset \left(0,\frac{\epsilon}{\delta} \right]$$
which gives:
$$k \leq \frac{\epsilon}{\delta}$$
i.e
$$\delta \leq\frac{\epsilon}{k}$$

Comment: what does `a` represent ? $ \left|\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{\delta} \right| $ ? I have difficulties with the implication $a \leq k \Rightarrow a \leq \frac{\epsilon}{\delta}$, how do you get it ?

Comment: $a$ is just here to show that if you *want* a quantity (called $a$) smaller than $\frac{\epsilon}{\delta}$ and you *know* that $a \leq k$ then you have to choose $\delta$ such that $\frac{\epsilon}{\delta} \leq k$.

$\left| (f(y)-f(x))/\delta\right|$ as no particular signification, the good quantity to consider is $|f(y)-f(x)|$ I was just trying to stay close to your question.

Comment: I think that $a\leq k \Rightarrow a \leq \frac{\epsilon}{\delta}$ can be understood graphically.

Draw the interval $(0,k]$. You know that $a$ is in this interval. Now how can you draw the interval $(0,\frac{\epsilon}{\delta}$ such that you are certain that $a$ is in this second interval ?

Answer (score 1):

The definition of Lipschitz (even the French one) says that a function $f$ is Lipschitz (on some interval $E$) if

$$|f(x) - f(y)| \leq k|x-y| $$

for some $k$, for any choice of $x,y \in E$.

Now, given any $\epsilon$, if we pick $\delta \leq \epsilon/k$, then for any pair 
$x,y \in E$ with $|x-y| < \delta$

$$|f(x)-f(y)| \leq k|x-y| < k \frac{\epsilon}{k} = \epsilon $$

which means by definition that $f$ is uniformely continuous on $E$.

Picking any $\delta \geq \epsilon/k$ makes no sense, what if I pick a huge $\delta$?